# Delete object and make new object with the pointer from the old object

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to c++ and I  have a class "Game" that contains a pointer to an object "PlayerShip".
When I create a second class "Harbour" I give that object pointer in the constructor and set a member variable with that object pointer so I can use it in the second class.

The question is that I need to replace this Object "PlayerShip" in the second class with a new object, but keep the same pointer ( because I use it in the first class "Game"). How can I do this?

```
class Game
{
   public:
      Game();
      virtual ~Game();

   private:
      //Player
      PlayerShip* playerShip_;
};


class Harbour
{
   public:
      Harbour(const int harbourId, PlayerShip* playerShip);
      virtual ~Harbour();

   private:
      //PlayerShip
      PlayerShip* playerShip_;

      void buyShip();
};

void Harbour::buyShip()
{
   delete playerShip_;
   playerShip_ = new PlayerShip();

}
```

Comment: Please [show](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46990117/edit) the relevant code.

Comment: Do you really need a new Object, or can you change the values of the old Object?

Comment: I really need a new object because the object has allot of values.

Comment: I do not understand the logic of your code. If you construct a harbor it contains an id of the ship that is going to be present in it? And if somebody buys that ship, it is immediately replaced by another ship? And where does the `playerShipId` come from?

Comment: FWIW you should be using smart pointers to express ownership and manage the lifetime of objects with dynamic storage duration.

Comment: The harbours contains a pointer to a PlayerShip. playerShipId has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Smart pointers are not allowed. It is for school.

Comment: What does `PlayerShip` look like? Is it a base class? What's the relationship between `Game` and `Harbour`? Who calls `buyShip`? Does a `Game` always outlive a `Harbour`? *"Smart pointers are not allowed. It is for school."* - Create your own simple version of `std::unique_ptr`, then. Have the destructor delete, disallow copying and add other features as you need them.

Comment: We do not know the wording of the assignment, but in general it is rare that using new and delete is the best design choice. When you do use new and delete, use a design pattern called RAII. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization

Comment: @ChristianHackl "*Create your own simple version of `std::unique_ptr`, then.*" - I would say `std::shared_ptr` instead. If the source `PlayerShip*` comes from `Game::playerShip_` and `buyShip()` deletes it, `Game` is boned if `unique_ptr` is used, but safe if `shared_ptr` is used